# T-SQL query group in date order (gaps and islands)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, grouping

I have a sample table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Aggregate
(
     vKey       INT
    ,dKey       INT
    ,StartTrip  DATETIME
    ,EndTrip    DATETIME
    ,Distance   INT
)
```

with some sample data like so

```
INSERT INTO #Aggregate
    (vKey, dKey, StartTrip, EndTrip, Distance )
VALUES
     (4940, 0, '2016-09-14 09:05:47.000', '2016-09-14 10:07:45.000', 25)
    ,(4940, 0, '2016-09-15 14:09:40.000', '2016-09-15 14:11:33.000', 35)
    ,(4940, 1202, '2016-09-16 17:07:04.000', '2016-09-16 18:07:04.000', 61)
    ,(4940, 0, '2016-09-26 16:43:03.000', '2016-09-26 16:44:52.000', 0)
    ,(4940, 0, '2016-09-28 11:13:41.000', '2016-09-28 11:14:33.000', 5)
    ,(4940, 1202, '2016-10-01 13:41:03.000', '2016-10-01 14:02:39.000', 500)
    ,(4940, 1202, '2016-10-01 21:52:14.000', '2016-10-01 21:54:28.000', 5)
    ,(4940, 0, '2016-10-01 10:27:44.000', '2016-10-01 10:36:24.000', 75)
```

I need to group the data in date order and in vKey/DKey combinations and present like so

```
vKey    dKey    StartTrip           EndTrip             Distance
4940    0       14/09/2016 09:05:47 15/09/2016 14:11:33 60
4940    1202    16/09/2016 17:07:04 16/09/2016 18:07:04 61
4940    0       26/09/2016 16:43:03 28/09/2016 11:14:33 5
4940    1202    01/10/2016 13:41:03 01/10/2016 21:54:28 505
4940    0       01/10/2016 10:27:44 01/10/2016 10:36:24 75
```

What is the best approach to take?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you elaborate on the sorting logic here?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM #Aggrgate ORDER BY vKey, StartTrip` would appear to give the result you want.

Comment: Yes, but I need to show aggregation on the distance along with MIN(StartTrip) and MaX(EndTrip), if you can see from my sample required output

Comment: gaps and islands...scary...too rich for my blood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select vKey
      ,dKey
      ,StartTrip = min(StartTrip) 
      ,EndTrip   = max(EndTrip) 
      ,Distance  = sum(Distance)
From (
      Select *
            ,Island = Row_Number() over (Partition By vKey Order by Month(StartTrip)) - Row_Number() over (Partition By vKey,dKey Order by StartTrip)
      From   #Aggrgate
     ) A
Group By Island,vKey,dKey
Order By min(StartTrip)
```

Returns

[image]

Comment: The Island calculations aren't correct.  I'm getting 1-1 = 43, 2-2 = 43 etc

Comment: That bug that I said I'd fixed well I didn't.  I've raised another question on the issue as I've included some details that won't fit in a comment.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40361594/tsql-order-by-on-occassion-doesnt-order-correctly  I'd appreciate it if you have a look see.