# TSQL Order BY on occasion doesn't order correctly

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-order-by

TSQL MSSQL 2008r2

I'm re-writing the question to try and make it clear what the issue is that I'm trying to explain.

I've got a stored proc that takes 3 parameters.  VehicleKey, StartDate and EndDateTime.  I'm querying a Data Warehouse db.  So the data shouldn't change.

When the proc is called with the same parameters then most of the time the results will be as expected but on some random occasions, with those same parameters, the results differ.  I'm querying a Data WH so the data doesn't change.

The problem is with the dynamic derived column "Island".

It's completely random.  The proc can be executed 20 times and give the expected results and then the next 2 will give incorrect results.

There can be 1 or more VehicleKey/DriverKey combinations in a given date range.

This is the problem query

```
SELECT
     A.VehicleKey
    ,A.NodeId
    ,A.DriverKey
    ,MIN(A.StartTrip)   'StartTrip'
    ,MAX(A.EndTrip)     'EndTrip'
    ,SUM(A.PrivOdo)     'Private'
    ,SUM(A.BusOdo)      'Business'
    ,SUM(A.TravOdo)     'Travel'
    ,SUM(A.PrivOdo + A.BusOdo + A.TravOdo )'Total'
FROM
(
    SELECT
         Island = ( ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.VehicleKey ORDER BY MONTH(StartTrip)) ) - ( ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.VehicleKey, T.DriverKey ORDER BY T.StartTrip) )
        ,NodeId
        ,VehicleKey
        ,DriverKey
        ,StartTrip
        ,EndTrip
        ,BusOdo
        ,PrivOdo
        ,TravOdo
    FROM 
        #xYTD_BPTotals T
) AS A
GROUP BY
     A.Island
    ,A.VehicleKey
    ,A.NodeId
    ,A.DriverKey
ORDER BY 
     A.VehicleKey
    ,MIN(A.StartTrip);
```

I am of the understanding that the ORDER BY should be on the outside of the derived table for it to take effect.

I think I've narrowed it down to the issue presenting itself only when a Vehicle has 2 or more DriverKey combinations.

for example, `Parameters VehicleKey 4865, StartDateTime = '2016-01-01', EndDateTime = '2016-10-31'`
This is the correct result - including Island column

```
VehicleKey    NodeId    DriverKey    Island    StartTrip              EndTrip               Private    Business    Travel    Total_
4865          458       0            0         2016-09-06 14:06:08    2016-09-28 17:02:08   54.75      737.83      0         792.58
4865          458       1202         134       2016-09-29 11:10:04    2016-09-30 17:25:51   0          211.32      0         211.32
4865          458       0            27        2016-10-03 07:39:25    2016-10-14 17:00:15   0          579.81      0         579.81
```

and this is when it's wrong.   `Parameters VehicleKey 4865, StartDateTime = '2016-01-01', EndDateTime = '2016-10-31'`
- including Island column
The first two rows here should be combined.

```
VehicleKey    NodeId    DriverKey    Island    StartTrip              EndTrip               Private    Business    Travel    Total_
4865          458       0            98        2016-09-06 14:06:08    2016-09-21 09:15:49   0          313.87      0         313.87
4865          458       0            -63       2016-09-21 09:21:10    2016-09-28 17:02:08   54.75      423.96      0         478.71
4865          458       1202         71        2016-09-29 11:10:04    2016-09-30 17:25:51   0          211.32      0         211.32
4865          458       0            27        2016-10-03 07:39:25    2016-10-14 17:00:15   0          579.81      0         579.81
```

If I show the first few rows from the derived table, I've broken down the "Island" column

```
SELECT
     Island = ( ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.VehicleKey ORDER BY MONTH(StartTrip)) ) - ( ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.VehicleKey, T.DriverKey ORDER BY T.StartTrip) )
    ,Island_x =( ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.VehicleKey ORDER BY MONTH(StartTrip)) )
    ,Island_y = ( ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.VehicleKey, T.DriverKey ORDER BY T.StartTrip) )
    ,NodeId
    ,VehicleKey
    ,DriverKey
    ,StartTrip
    ,EndTrip
    ,BusOdo
    ,PrivOdo
    ,TravOdo
FROM 
    #xYTD_BPTotals T
```

The correct result should be

```
Island  Island_x    Island_y    NodeId  VehicleKey  DriverKey   StartTrip   EndTrip BusOdo  PrivOdo TravOdo
0   1   1   24901   4865    0   2016-09-06 14:06:08 2016-09-06 14:08:50 0   0   0
0   2   2   24901   4865    0   2016-09-06 15:39:14 2016-09-06 15:40:53 114 0   0
0   3   3   24901   4865    0   2016-09-08 11:06:43 2016-09-08 11:07:23 0   0   0
0   4   4   24901   4865    0   2016-09-08 11:12:03 2016-09-08 11:12:26 20  0   0
0   5   5   24901   4865    0   2016-09-08 11:19:20 2016-09-08 11:19:52 1   0   0
0   6   6   24901   4865    0   2016-09-08 11:26:58 2016-09-08 11:27:56 88  0   0
0   7   7   24901   4865    0   2016-09-08 11:33:40 2016-09-08 11:35:02 1   0   0
0   8   8   24901   4865    0   2016-09-12 09:08:53 2016-09-12 09:10:42 34  0   0
```

but I sometimes get this with the same input paramaters.

```
Island  Island_x    Island_y    NodeId  VehicleKey  DriverKey   StartTrip   EndTrip BusOdo  PrivOdo TravOdo
98  1   1   24901   4865    0   2016-09-06 14:06:08 2016-09-06 14:08:50 0   0   0
98  2   2   24901   4865    0   2016-09-06 15:39:14 2016-09-06 15:40:53 114 0   0
98  3   3   24901   4865    0   2016-09-08 11:06:43 2016-09-08 11:07:23 0   0   0
98  4   4   24901   4865    0   2016-09-08 11:12:03 2016-09-08 11:12:26 20  0   0
98  5   5   24901   4865    0   2016-09-08 11:19:20 2016-09-08 11:19:52 1   0   0
98  6   6   24901   4865    0   2016-09-08 11:26:58 2016-09-08 11:27:56 88  0   0
98  7   7   24901   4865    0   2016-09-08 11:33:40 2016-09-08 11:35:02 1   0   0
98  8   8   24901   4865    0   2016-09-12 09:08:53 2016-09-12 09:10:42 34  0   0
```

Why is the "Island" calculated column wrong?  1-1 = 0 not 98.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Dumb question... Are Start and End Trip datetime fields or are they actually strings?

Comment: They are DATETIME fields.

Comment: I don't think you have an ORDER BY problem, I think you have a GROUP BY problem. I also don't think anything is "wrong" - I think you are getting two different values for Island (but you aren't exposing those in the output, so it's not obvious).

Comment: Yes, I'm getting two different results for Island but this is only when the query is in the wrong order, I can show this is the question above.

Comment: I still don't understand where anything is in the wrong order.

Comment: This is what makes it hard to explain and why I'm struggling to understand where it's going wrong.  I've updated the question with more information

Comment: I still don't understand "wrong" - is it that Island = 98 instead of island = 0? In the last two output samples, all of those rows seem to be in the same order regardless of the value of island. So this isn't an ordering problem. In the query above that, you suggest that two rows with different Island values should be combined, but this is not possible. You are grouping by Island, and they have different values, therefore they must appear on separate rows. Maybe start simpler; explain exactly what you are trying to accomplish (sample data, desired results) instead of saying ordering is wrong.

Comment: Why is row_number function represented by "Island" showing 98 when the answer to x-y (1-1) is 0?  This is a follow up to a gaps and islands question I had http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40307623/t-sql-query-group-in-date-order-gaps-and-islands

Comment: Something must be different when you get 0 and when you get 98. The same query will give the same output given the same input unless some of the input (e.g. the underlying data) has changed. Why are you sometimes using ORDER BY StartTrip and sometimes ORDER BY MONTH(StartTrip)?

Comment: but I'm querying a DataWH so the underlying data is the same.

Comment: You have a data warehouse stored in a #temp table (`#xYTD_BPTotals`)? (And my point is, maybe that is getting loaded differently sometimes - you could try running your query against the real data instead of against whatever you have stuffed into this #temp table.)

Comment: No, not all the DataWH.  Just the rows from the tables that I want.  I'm populating the #temp table using an ORDER BY clause so that data should be consistanty populated in the correct order right?

Comment: Data in a table isn't stored in any "correct" order...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **EDIT - @YourData now looks like your raw table**

```
Declare @YourTable table (VehicleKey int,NodeId int,DriverKey int,StartTrip datetime,EndTrip datetime,PrivOdo decimal(10,2),BusOdo decimal(10,2), TravOdo decimal(10,2))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(4865,458,0   ,'2016-09-06 14:06:08','2016-09-21 09:15:49',0    ,313.87,0),
(4865,458,0   ,'2016-09-21 09:21:10','2016-09-28 17:02:08',54.75,423.96,0),
(4865,458,1202,'2016-09-29 11:10:04','2016-09-30 17:25:51',0    ,211.32,0),
(4865,458,0   ,'2016-10-03 07:39:25','2016-10-14 17:00:15',0    ,579.81,0)

Select VehicleKey
      ,NodeID
      ,VehicleKey
      ,DriverKey
      ,StartTrip = min(StartTrip)
      ,EndTrip   = max(EndTrip)
      ,Private   = sum(PrivOdo)
      ,Business  = sum(BusOdo)
      ,Travel    = sum(TravOdo)
      ,Total     = sum(PrivOdo + BusOdo + TravOdo )
 From (
 Select  Island = ( ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY VehicleKey ORDER BY MONTH(StartTrip)) ) - ( ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY VehicleKey, DriverKey ORDER BY StartTrip) )
        ,*
 From @YourTable 
) A
Group By Island,VehicleKey,NodeID,VehicleKey,DriverKey
Order By min(StartTrip)
```

Returns

[image]

FYI - The sub-query produces

[image]

Comment: Thanks John, are you suggesting that I double up and do another Island query?

Comment: @Mountaineer Not at all.   I see you posted some actual core data.  Give me a moment

Comment: @Mountaineer  The sub-query was presumably your raw data.  The Island is the only derived column necessary.  Not sure what you are doing with X and Y.

Comment: I was trying to show that when the results go wrong then Island, which is the derived column based on the x - y, gives the wrong answer.  as you can see from above, x = 1 and y = 1 but Island shows the answer as 98.

Comment: @Mountaineer In the "When not working"  what is your expected result?

Comment: @Mountaineer Just to be be clear.  The Island is derived, dynamic grouping

Comment: The same as "when working".  This is a stored proc when executed with the same input parameters gives different results sometimes.

Comment: Yes, I know Island is derived, dynamic grouping. But with the proc should give the same results with the same input parameters everytime not most of the time.

Comment: @Mountaineer OK, so your issue is that Island sometimes shows as 98 or 0 or something else, BUT it is still a consistent grouping?   If so, you need to understand that SQL does not query data in a consistent order.  The first part of the Island calc Partition By VehicleKey Order By month(StartTrip).  This vehicle key could land in any sequence... it is a partition not an order by.  Perhaps you can add VehicleKey to the Order by clause as well.

Comment: I thought when I put the ORDER BY clause of  `ORDER BY A.VehicleKey ,MIN(A.StartTrip)` outside of the derived table would ensure SQL queried the data is the correct and consistant order.

Comment: I've changed the first row_number function of the "island column to include VehicleKey in the order by clause and I still get the same issue.

Comment: @Mountaineer Before the MONTH()?  Just curious, why is it important that the island # be consistent?  Again, it is a on-the-fly grouping.

Comment: Yes, before the Month().  For the parameters that I've included in the question the correct results should be 3 rows. But sometimes I get the 4 rows. The underlying data doesn't change so the results should be the same.  Am I understanding this wrong?

Comment: @Mountaineer one possible suggestion is change Order By  MONTH(StartTrip) to just StartTrip.   Other than that, I've got nothing to explain why you would get variable results

Comment: I've changed the Island to `Island = ( ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.VehicleKey ORDER BY T.VehicleKey, T.StartTrip, T.DriverKey) ) - ( ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.VehicleKey, T.DriverKey ORDER BY T.VehicleKey, T.StartTrip, T.DriverKey ) )` and this looks to have worked.

Comment: @Mountaineer Well Done!